# Update Android UI doesnt work

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

im now searching for 2 hours for a small error that makes this code doesnt work:

The Activity:

```
UpdateThread t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    t = new UpdateThread(this, this);
    t.start();
    super.onResume();
}
```

And the Thread:

```
public UpdateThread(FullscreenActivity a, Context c) {
    this.c = c;
    this.a = a;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    if(enabled) return;
    enabled = true;
    while(true) {
        a.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) a.findViewById(R.id.view);
                view.removeAllViews();
                    try {
                        TextView t = new TextView(c);
                        t.setText("asd");
                        t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        t.setX(22);
                        t.setY(123);
                        t.setScaleX(0.9f);
                        t.setScaleY(0.9f);
                        t.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                        view.addView(t);
                    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                Log.d("Finished drawing!"," drawed!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Layout XML File:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:id="@+id/asd"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This code should add a TextView to the FullscreenActivity, but nothing happens.

Im using Android level 12, all Software up to date, my phone is the SGS3.
Thank you for you help, im looking forward to the solution :)

Comment: With which value is `enabled` initialized?

Comment: enabled is false. Its just a protection against multiple instaces of this thread. The Thread starts normally and is running correctly. Log.d("",""); works correctly, but updating the UI doesnt work

Comment: Add the activity layout.

Comment: Sorry, where should I add an activity layout?

Comment: Edit your question and add that xml layout file, maybe the `RelativeLayout` where you add the `TextViews` is hidden for some reason.

Comment: Can you remove the `view.removeAllViews();` line and see how it goes?

Comment: Still nothing happens